# Как вставить изображение в текст

Tags: html, css, img

мне нужно вставить изображение в текст c помощью html и css, как это сделать вот так
[image: Вот так например]

Comment: `background-clip: text`

Comment: Где-то это уже было, вроде у АлександраТТ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
background-image:url("Путь к нужной картинке");

background-size: 60px 60px; //размер подгонишь если без этого свойства будет криво стоять

-webkit-background-clip: text; //это свойство что бы браузер понял что фон должен быть формой как текст.

-webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); //это свойство задает прозрачные буквы тексту что бы фон был виден
```

Comment: ,извините за тупой вопрос, но все же какой селектор нужно использовать к этому файлу, и по возможности добавьте html код